# Time complexity of program determining if two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, hashtable, permutation

I have written a program to determine if two strings are permutations of one another. I am trying to do so using a hash table. Here is my code:

```
bool permutation(string word1, string word2) {

    unordered_map<char, int> myMap1;
    unordered_map<char, int> myMap2;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    if (word1.length() == word2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
            count1++;
            count2++;
            for (int j = 0; j < word1.length(); j++) {
                if (word1[i] == word1[j] && myMap1.find(word1[i]) == myMap1.end()) {
                    count1++;
                }
                if (word2[i] == word2[j] && myMap2.find(word1[i]) == myMap2.end()) {
                    count2++;
                }
            }
            myMap1.insert({word1[i], count1});
            myMap2.insert({word2[i], count2});
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    return (myMap1.size() == myMap2.size());
}

int main() {

    string word1;
    string word2;
    getline(cin, word1);
    getline(cin, word2);

    bool result = permutation(word1, word2);

    return 0;
}
```

I believe the time complexity of the above code is O(n^2). I couldn't think of an algorithm that didn't involve using nested loops. Is there a faster way to do this using a hash table?

Comment: Why do you need to use a hash table? Sort the characters in the strings and if the two sorted strings are the same, then one is  a permutation of the other.

Comment: @latedeveloper Sorting would be n log(n), whereas this could be done in linear time.

Comment: I'm trying to get better with hash tables so I wanted to try and use one for this program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep.

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace {

bool permutation(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) {
  std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> freqdiff;
  // alternatively, std::size_t freqdiff[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {};
  for (char c : word1) {
    // alternatively, freqdiff[(unsigned char)c]++;
    freqdiff[c]++;
  }
  for (char c : word2) {
    // alternatively, freqdiff[(unsigned char)c]--;
    freqdiff[c]--;
  }
  for (auto i : freqdiff) {
    // alternatively, i != 0
    if (i.second != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool permutation_with_array(const std::string& word1,
                            const std::string& word2) {
  std::size_t freqdiff[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {};
  for (char c : word1) {
    freqdiff[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)]++;
  }
  for (char c : word2) {
    freqdiff[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)]--;
  }
  for (std::size_t i : freqdiff) {
    if (i != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
}

int main() {
  std::string word1;
  std::string word2;
  std::getline(std::cin, word1);
  std::getline(std::cin, word2);
  std::cout << permutation(word1, word2) << '\n';
  std::cout << permutation_with_array(word1, word2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why bother with a hash table - why not simply use an array?

Comment: @latedeveloper The hash table could be faster for short strings (because we don't need to initialize a length-256 array), generalizes better to Unicode (because then the table has a million entries), but mostly because the OP requested it.

Comment: a) We do need initialise the hash table, however.  b) YAGNI, c) Good point.

Comment: An array-based approach wouldn't scale well, which would be a problem if you wanted to add Unicode support.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Does "freqdiff[c]++" create a key-value pair, if it doesn't already exist, with c as the key and however many times it increments as the value?

Comment: @CheetahBongos Yes. The first time, the value for `c` is default constructed to zero, then incremented (resp. decremented).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR I wanted to test the solutions (including my own): David's map based answer performs decently well (it is a lot more generic), his array based solution performs very well, my own solution was only slightly faster but also slightly less readable (probably not worth it).

In all honesty, when I saw this, I couldn't believe David's answer with the unordered map could possibly have the lowest time complexity. (well possibly theoretically, but not in practice)

I'm usually writing in C, so I have no idea what kind of optimisations C++ offers with these data structures or how well they perform in real life. So I decided to test it.

So I set up some tests on my i7, to test the performance of the various solutions, with some slight adaptations ([source code here](https://gist.github.com/WorkOfArtiz/08c042991ade9ed20570e073d410e36c))

I ran the programs 100000 times on 1) 2 permutations and 2) 2 different words

The results came in as follows:

```
PERM original
======================
PERMUTATIONS OF SAME WORD
real 104.73
user 104.61
sys 0.06

DIFFERENT WORDS
real 104.24
user 104.16
sys 0.02

PERM David map
======================
PERMUTATIONS OF SAME WORD
real 2.46
user 2.44
sys 0.00

DIFFERENT WORDS
real 2.45
user 2.42
sys 0.02

PERM David array
======================
PERMUTATIONS OF SAME WORD
real 0.15
user 0.14
sys 0.00

DIFFERENT WORDS
real 0.14
user 0.14
sys 0.00

PERM Me
======================
PERMUTATIONS OF SAME WORD
real 0.13
user 0.13
sys 0.00

DIFFERENT WORDS
real 0.14
user 0.12
sys 0.01
```

Comment: I guess my horse came in last :( It's amazing how much of a difference the nested for loops can cause. Very interesting